# librement.sty for standalone latex documents

Tags: packages, templates

I am new to latex, and I love the template that was used for creating the [Debian Administrators Book](http://debian-handbook.info/contribute/)

The authors use a latex style `librement.sty` (in the sources  `dblatex/librement.sty`).
Is it possible to use this in a standalone latex doc to create new documents?

[Some people have already asked](http://debian-handbook.info/2012/liberation-fund-completed-release-in-the-next-few-weeks/#comment-596), and it seems that some changes will be needed, but I was wondering how much knowledge I would need of latex to do this (I am novice).

Has anyone already done it and could post the changes needed?

The Git repository:

```
$ git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/debian-handbook/debian-handbook.git
```

Comment: This seems to be a LaTeX2e package, so should be usable with any class. That said, a lot of the code seems to be design-related, so it really _should_ be a class file.

Comment: Did you actually try to use the package, and if so did you encounter any issues?

Comment: Sure, tried it but without luck. It seems that there are dependencies with [dblatex](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/), but even after putting all styles in a directory there were complaints about possibly using xetex etc. At this stage I have no idea if a normal "article" can be created using this style and compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It would be good if you would register on this site, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I find that I can get the package to at least be loaded using XeLaTeX with

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifxetex,librement}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

if I have a local copy of [`dblatex`](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/) and [`multirow2`](http://helgafell.rhi.hi.is/texmf/tex/latex/dblatex/multirow2.sty), giving a single error (`Missing number ...`) which I can simply bypass. However, I'm suspicious that this is going to work for a real case, not only due to the error but also as the dependencies are odd. For example, why do I have to load `ifxetex` manually (there is an error if you do not), and what is the difference between `multirow2` and the standard `multirow` pacakge. I would therefore suspect that to use this package you need the appropriate class, *etc.*